# Issue with app activities flow using Facebook SDK for Android

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I'm following the Facebook tutorial on how to implement the Facebook Login flow to my Android app. It works fine with UiLifecycleHelper and Session implementations:

```
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
private Session.StatusCallback callback = 
    new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, 
            SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};
```

In the onSessionStateChange i check if the state is opened and start the MainActivity, and everything works ok.
My doubt here is: do i have to reimplement this code (UiLifeCycleHelper, onSessionStateChange) on every Activity of my app or not? And if not, how i can control the Facebook Session flow through the activities?

Answer (score 0):

**Works for Facebook Android SDK 3.X only**

You have to reimplement this code for each activity which uses Facebook SDK. Moving all Facebook-related code to a superclass can be a good solution (e.g. FacebookSdkActivity).

To get the session anywhere in your app, use Session.getActiveSession() method. For example, if you want to check if a user is connected to Facebook, you can use:

```
Session.getActiveSession() != null && Session.getActiveSession().isOpened();
```